# How to pass inverted commas through URL in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I wanted to pass two parameters through the URL. One with varchar data type and the other with int. The varchar one includes characters, numbers and `-` for example: `wfsjjhc122-hdggb11-2weeee-yu`. When I am passing this through URL via queryString. It gives me an error saying incorrect syntax near `wfsjjhc122-`

I am currently not using quotes. The query string is like `pagname.cfm?id=wfsjjhc122-hdggb11-2weeee-yu&no=123`.

Should it be something like `pagname.cfm?id='wfsjjhc122-hdggb11-2weeee-yu'&no=123`? If so how can I pass inverted commas? Currently when I am trying to do so but browser is automatically adding `%27` instead of `'`.

```
<td bgcolor="#bgColor#"><a href="pagname.cfm?id='#iD#'&no=#no#">View</a></td>
```

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/urlencodedformat.html and https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encodeforurl.html check if these help.

Comment: @Nik database value don't have quotes, I wanted to append quotes. Is it possible?

Comment: By "inverted comma" I think you mean the single-quote or single-tick `'`. These are not necessary for the query string and in fact will just become part of your value as you are seeing. The `%27` is the URL encoded value of the `'` character. AFAIK you should just be using `<a href="pagname.cfm?id=#encodeForURL(iD)#&no=#encodeForURL(no)#">` (as Nik suggested). What is the actual error message and actual value when you are encountering the incorrect syntax error?